# Emacs eww cannot access https sites

Tags: emacs

here's my proxy setup:

```
(setq url-proxy-services '(("no_proxy" . "my-corp-proxy")
                           ("http" . "my-corp-proxy:8080")
                           ("https" . "my-port-proxy:8080")))
```

I can use eww to access http sites ok, but when I try to access https sites I get this response:
[image]
I've installed gnutls as well, if I evaluate `(gnutls-available-p)` I get a `t`.

any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem and I have finally got it working.

I applied the patch in https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2016-03/msg01106.html

Then to solve

> error in process filter: url-http-generic-filter: Wrong type argument:
>   number-or-marker-p, http/1.1

I just had to add a line to url-http.el:462 which was

```
(skip-chars-forward "HTTP/")        ; Skip HTTP Version
(skip-chars-forward "http/")        ; Skip HTTP Version
```